# Netbook won't start after trying RAM

Tags: boot, memory, bios, samsung-laptop

I tried installing 2gb ddr3 RAM to my Samsung N150 netbook now it won't turn on. I tried to rrturn it orginal RAM but still wont start. The BIOS isn't probably starting because the Samsung splash screen does not show but the fans and hdd are spinning. The power indicator light is also blinking at a constant interval (I cant remember if thats normal) and the disk indicator also lights ocasionaly.

Comment: You might have bent or damaged a pin - check with a magnifying glass & torch...

Comment: As far I can see there where no physical damage to either the slot of the old RAM